# c# WindowsForms databinding does not update all fields

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

having a windows forms app with several fields that should be updated by databindng. 
All fields will be contained in the 'this' part and all will be shown in the attached labels, but not the [BaustelleName].

[PropertyChanged?.Invoke(**this**, e);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FalnO.png) 
[ScreenShoot one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAcdC.png)

The source to work with is:

```
    public string BaustelleName
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.sName) ? null : sName; }
        set
        {
            sName = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BaustelleName"));
        }
    }

    public string BaustelleZusatz
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.sZusatz) ? null : sZusatz; }
        set
        {
            sZusatz = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BaustelleZusatz"));
        }
    }
```

...

```
    protected void BindControls()
    {
        try
        {
            Binding bnd = null;
            cBindung bnd_Helper = new cBindung();

            // txt_Baustelle ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            parent.txt_Baustelle.DataBindings.Clear();
            bnd = new Binding("Text", this, "BaustelleNr", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            parent.txt_Baustelle.DataBindings.Add(bnd);

            //lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl1.Text = adr.VornameName; ----------------------------------------------
            parent.lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl1.DataBindings.Clear();
            bnd = new Binding("Text", this, "BaustelleName");
            parent.lbl_AdrKunde_Zl1.DataBindings.Add(bnd);

            //lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl2.Text = adr.Zusatz; ---------------------------------------------------
            parent.lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl2.DataBindings.Clear();
            bnd = new Binding("Text", this, "BaustelleZusatz");
            parent.lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl2.DataBindings.Add(bnd);     //Zusatz
```

...

```
    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

... same for other fields.
I've found that the getter for [BaustelleName] nevver get called, whereas all others are called everytime the [InvokePropertyChanged] is called.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you're adding the binding to the wrong label: you're adding it to lbl_ArdKunde instead of lbl_AdrBaustelle

```
//lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl1.Text = adr.VornameName; ---------------------------------------
    parent.lbl_AdrBaustelle_Zl1.DataBindings.Clear();
    bnd = new Binding("Text", this, "BaustelleName");
    parent.lbl_AdrKunde_Zl1.DataBindings.Add(bnd);
```

Comment: @nicoYour'e right; Thank you very much and apologize for this stupid question. As we say in German: "_Sometimes you do not see the hand in front of your eyes_"